# Are homogeneous cut point spaces T2?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. 
X is called *homogeneous*, if for all $x, y \in X$ there is a homeomorphism $f: X \rightarrow X$ such that $f(x) = y$.  
$x \in X$ is called *cut point*, if $X \setminus \{x\}$ is not connected. It is a *strong cut point*, if $X \setminus \{x\}$ has exactly two components.

$X$ is a *(strong) cut point space*, if $X$ is connected and each $x \in X$ is a (strong) cut point.

Is a homogeneous (strong) cut point space T2?

Notes

1. It is easy to see that a cut point in a connected space is either open or closed (as a set).
   Hence a homogeneous cut point space is T1.
2. Typical homogeneous cut point spaces are the reals, the long line without $0$, or the "two sided long line". Or some refinements thereof (for instance, [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616041/is-every-hausdorff-homogeneous-space-also-regular)). Of course, all these are T2.
3. The Khalimsky line (see [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1999-127-09/S0002-9939-99-04839-X/S0002-9939-99-04839-X.pdf)) is an example of a non-T1 cut point space. Of course, it is not homogeneous.
4. The cofinite topology on an infinite set is homogeneous, but does not contain any cut point.